# vim - automatically formatting golang source code when saving

Tags: go, vim

I'm using vim with the [vim-golang](https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang) plugin. This plugin comes with [a function called :Fmt](https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang/blob/master/ftplugin/go/fmt.vim) that "reformats" the source code using [gofmt](http://gofmt.com/), a command-line executable.

I want to invoke the :Fmt function each time that I save the file, so it is continuously re-formatted. I think this should be done with a [autocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) directive. But I have two doubts:

1. I could not find a way to execute the function. I tried writting Fmt and :Fmt at the end of the autocmd line, but it didn't seem to work. I think I miss something, like "call".
2. I want this to happen only when saving a file of filetype 'go'. I don't know how to combine those two conditions - I can activate variables depending on the file type, and I can do small stuff, like removing trailing spaces, whenever a file is saved, but separatedly.

So this is what I have so far:

```
" I can set variables for go like this
autocmd FileType go setlocal noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 nolist

" I can clean trailing spaces(conserving cursor position) on save like this
autocmd BufWritePre * kz|:%s/\s\+$//e|'z

" None of these worked:
autocmd BufWritePre,FileType go Fmt
autocmd BufWritePre,FileType go :Fmt
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `FileType` event doesn't fire on buffer writes; `BufWritePre` is the correct one, but you need to provide a file pattern, e.g. `*.go`:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.go Fmt
```

The only downside is that this duplicates the detection of the *go* filetype. You could delegate this by hooking into the `FileType` event, and then define the formatting autocmd for each Go buffer by using the special `<buffer>` pattern:

```
autocmd FileType go autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> Fmt
```

This has the downside that if the filetype ever gets set multiple times, you'll run the formatting multiple times, too. That could be solved via a custom `:augroup`, but now it becomes really complex. Or, if you're really sure that this is the only `BufWritePre` autocmd for Go buffers, you could use `:autocmd! BufWritePre ...` (with a `!`).

Comment: Wow, incredibly extensive answer, thanks a lot! I ended up using the second option - I don't plan to reset the filetype at all. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add `silent` if you need to normal output from the `Fmt` command (I kept seeing `X lines filtered`):
`autocmd FileType go autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> silent Fmt`

Comment: It is already in `vim-gocode` plugin https://github.com/Blackrush/vim-gocode/blob/master/ftplugin/go/fmt.vim#L20

Comment: The scenario is coding in a boarding gate. What if code has an error and I do need to save the file even with an error? In my case, it did not let me save the file. Is there a way to force saving in such cases?

Comment: PS! from [Go 1.4](http://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.4#misc) (where misc/vim was removed), you have to install https://github.com/vim-jp/vim-go-extra for @IngoKarkat's instructions to work.

Alternatively, browse for other options at the [Go GitHub wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins).

Comment: Forgive me if this is a foolish question, but under what scenario would the Filetype be set multiple times?

Comment: @2-bits: For example, when you temporarily change the filetype (e.g. to edit a huge string literal containing XML), and then `:setf go` again. Some plugins might also be programmed this way. But it's unlikely, yes, so mostly nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

If you use folds, gofmt messes these up (it opens closed folds, closes open ones).
To keep folds as they where use the following autocommand

```
autocmd FileType go autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> execute "normal! mz:mkview\<esc>:Fmt\<esc>:loadview\<esc>`z"
```

It uses the z register to mark the cursor position because :mkview and :loadview (wich save and restores the folds) move the cursor for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

For those not using the plugin, this should work:

```
autocmd FileType go autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> execute "normal! mz:mkview\<esc>:%!gofmt-safe\<esc>:loadview\<esc>`z"
```

Add the following script to your `PATH`, this is needed otherwise gofmt will nuke the file if there are any syntax errors. This can be dangerous if you type `:x` for instance.

`gofmt-safe`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

orig=$(mktemp)
fmt=$(mktemp)

cat > "$orig"

<"$orig" gofmt "$@" > "$fmt" 2>/dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    cat "$fmt"
else
    cat "$orig"
fi

rm -f "$orig" "$fmt"
```

If you want live dangerously without this script, you can replace `%!gofmt-safe` with `%!gofmt` in the `autocmd` line. This has the benefit of showing you syntax errors on `:w`. Just make sure not to type `:x` or `:wq`.